# How Do I Make This CSS Mount animation Go In Reverse?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LarkRanger/2h3fcet0/12/) I have a small `div` with an opacity animation.
The animation plays correctly when the state changes to `true` and the component is mounted
and the `div` fades in.
However the animation does not play when the component is unmounted when the state goes to `false`.
I have the animation set as `both`, and I tried also applying a reverse animation (from 1 to 0) but it just ends up playing right after the first one and I end up with no square.

How can I make this fade animation play in reverse when the component disappears?

Edit:
I did not mention this is done in React.
My solution eventually was to just use a library for animation, which made this efortless.
I'm leaving the question up though in case others have vanilla solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found sort of a hacky way to solve this. You might find something better later on, but for now, this works.

I've created a class `.hide` which sets opacity to 0 and visibility to hidden, which will be added to the box. The initial insertion animation is the same. But for exiting, I've applied a transition property to the box. When you click a second time, I've wrapped the setVisible() method in a setTimeout(), that has a delay timing the same as the transition duration for `.hide`.

This will allow the box to fade out first, and then the setVisible() method will be called.

If you don't want to use a setTimeout(), you can add an eventListener to the box for *transitionend*, and then call setVisible() once that is done.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32y8vjus/1/

PS: In the fiddle, I'm changing the background color to show that the transition happens before the box is removed. You can change that to opacity.